# PHP Logic - For each Inside While Loop duplicating items from MySQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around this scenario.  I've got 3 tables, typical `tag`, `post`, `tag_post` mapped tables.

I have a page that displays the posts, basically just does the query `SELECT * from POST`, then inside the while statement for these results I query `SELECT tag_id FROM tag_post WHERE post_id = ?` with `?` being the `post_id` from the parent while loop.  I also have the HTML for each post inside this parent loop.

I obtain the `tag_id` values from this second query, and then lower in my HTML create an additional `foreach ($tagIds as $tag) {}` to fetch the `tag_name` values from the tag table.

My problem is, every time the loop runs, the tags from the more recent iteration are included.  So my second post has all the tags from the first post, third has tags from all three etc.  I know my problem is that I'm running the HTML twice, but as I said I can't fathom how to correct this.

Am I taking too many steps?  Could it be done much more efficiently than how I'm doing it?

I can post code if needed.

Comment: can't you use a single query using `JOIN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all required data with a single query:

```
"SELECT p.* FROM post p
INNER JOIN tag_post tp ON (tp.post_id = p.id)
INNER JOIN tag t ON (t.id = tp.tag_id)
WHERE p.post_id = ?"
```

I guess you are currently accumulating data in some arrays and you do not empty the `tags` array. So in each iteration new tags always added to that list.

Comment: For the sake of a quick fix to let me go on about my day, how do I empty the `tags` array after each loop?

I will certainly get that query you suggested functioning later tonight.  I'm just not familiar enough with `JOIN` to do this right now.

Comment: Sorry, simply `unset($tagIds)` I was able to run the loop again without repeating.  Thanks so much.  As I said I'll look at the `JOIN` query tonight.  Thanks a million!

Comment: It should work. You need to empty tags array when you switched to the next post (in the first line after `foreach ($posts as $post) {`)